# usage of poly function for multipe variables in data frame

Tags: r

[R]
I have a table Boston which has 14 quantitative predictors. I want to use poly function to iterate over all the predictors. 
Using individually for every predictor works eg.
`lm(crim~poly(nox,3))`

Having trouble in looping through all predictors:
I tried using,

```
colnames(Boston) = >
[1] "crim"    "zn"      "indus"   "chas"    "nox"     "rm"      "age"... 

for(index in colnames(Boston)){
  lm(crim~poly(index,3))
}
```

I get error :
Error in poly(A = index, 3) : 
  'degree' must be less than number of unique points

Is there any other way to refer the variable name in index correctly in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following loop works for me, however you should lower the degrees (polynomial) in case that the length of the unique (column) points are less than 3,

```
data(Boston)

nams = colnames(Boston)[-1]

for (i in nams) {

  cat(i, " ", length(unique(Boston[, i])), '\n')

  degree = 3

  if (length(unique(Boston[, i])) < degree) {

    degree = length(unique(Boston[, i])) - 1
  }

  tmp_formula = as.formula(paste(c('crim ~ poly(', i, ",", degree, ")"), collapse = ""))

  print(tmp_formula)

  fit = lm(tmp_formula, data = Boston)
}
```

example output:

```
zn   26 
crim ~ poly(zn, 3)
indus   76 
crim ~ poly(indus, 3)
chas   2 
crim ~ poly(chas, 1)
nox   81 
crim ~ poly(nox, 3)
rm   446 
crim ~ poly(rm, 3)
age   356 
crim ~ poly(age, 3)
dis   412 
crim ~ poly(dis, 3)
rad   9 
crim ~ poly(rad, 3)
tax   66 
crim ~ poly(tax, 3)
ptratio   46 
crim ~ poly(ptratio, 3)
black   357 
crim ~ poly(black, 3)
lstat   455 
crim ~ poly(lstat, 3)
medv   229 
crim ~ poly(medv, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks @lampros !